# write parent function var in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

How do you change the value of a variable in the parent function in javascript

For example:

```
function parent() {
     var changeme = 0;

     function child() {
          changeme = 1;
     }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your current work would do that if you run it.

Comment: it will work because `changeme` is a closure variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `changeme` within `child()` is referring to the `changeme` in `parent()`. Just call `child()` and it will change it.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/eV985/)

```
function parent() {
    var changeme = 0;

    function child() {
        changeme = 1;
    }
    child();

    alert(changeme);
}
parent();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got what you need. You just need to call the method to change the variable value:-

Check this, this should log 0, 1.

```
function parent() {
     var changeme = 0;
    console.log(changeme);

     function child() {
          changeme = 1;
     }
    child();
    console.log(changeme);
}
parent();
```